# django-allauth No module named 'django.core.email'

Tags: django, django-allauth

I installed django-allauth and I'm able to login and logout with my admin superuser account. However, when I try to sign up, I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError at /accounts/signup/
No module named 'django.core.email'
```

Included config in my settings.py:

```
SITE_ID = 1

# django-allauth configuration
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT = 'home'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE = False

# configure email
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.email.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

I don't have a urls.py or views.py file for the accounts since this is taken care of by the allauth plugin.

The full traceback is:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup/

Django Version: 3.2.6
Python Version: 3.8.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django_select2',
 'crispy_forms',
 'rest_framework',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'accounts',
 'gradebook']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Doug\.virtualenvs\upgradetools-YX5Y8vBO\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Doug\.virtualenvs\upgradetools-YX5Y8vBO\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Doug\.virtualenvs\upgradetools-YX5Y8vBO\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Doug\.virtualenvs\upgradetools-YX5Y8vBO\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Doug\.virtualenvs\upgradetools-YX5Y8vBO\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py", line 89, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Doug\.virtualenvs\upgradetools-YX5Y8vBO\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\views.py", line 230, in dispatch
    return super(SignupView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Doug\.virtualenvs\upgradetools-YX5Y8vBO\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\views.py", line 74, in dispatch
    response = super(RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin, self).dispatch(
  File "C:\Users\Doug\.virtualenvs\upgradetools-YX5Y8vBO\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\views.py", line 204, in dispatch
    return super(CloseableSignupMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Doug\.virtualenvs\upgradetools-YX5Y8vBO\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Doug\.virtualenvs\upgradetools-YX5Y8vBO\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\views.py", line 102, in post
    response = self.form_valid(form)
  File "C:\Users\Doug\.virtualenvs\upgradetools-YX5Y8vBO\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\views.py", line 248, in form_valid
    return complete_signup(
  File "C:\Users\Doug\.virtualenvs\upgradetools-YX5Y8vBO\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\utils.py", line 209, in complete_signup
    return perform_login(
  File "C:\Users\Doug\.virtualenvs\upgradetools-YX5Y8vBO\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\utils.py", line 172, in perform_login
    send_email_confirmation(request, user, signup=signup, email=email)
  File "C:\Users\Doug\.virtualenvs\upgradetools-YX5Y8vBO\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\utils.py", line 346, in send_email_confirmation
    email_address.send_confirmation(request, signup=signup)
  File "C:\Users\Doug\.virtualenvs\upgradetools-YX5Y8vBO\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\models.py", line 62, in send_confirmation
    confirmation.send(request, signup=signup)
  File "C:\Users\Doug\.virtualenvs\upgradetools-YX5Y8vBO\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\models.py", line 169, in send
    get_adapter(request).send_confirmation_mail(request, self, signup)
  File "C:\Users\Doug\.virtualenvs\upgradetools-YX5Y8vBO\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\adapter.py", line 464, in send_confirmation_mail
    self.send_mail(email_template, emailconfirmation.email_address.email, ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Doug\.virtualenvs\upgradetools-YX5Y8vBO\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\adapter.py", line 136, in send_mail
    msg.send()
  File "C:\Users\Doug\.virtualenvs\upgradetools-YX5Y8vBO\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 284, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "C:\Users\Doug\.virtualenvs\upgradetools-YX5Y8vBO\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 241, in get_connection
    self.connection = get_connection(fail_silently=fail_silently)
  File "C:\Users\Doug\.virtualenvs\upgradetools-YX5Y8vBO\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\__init__.py", line 34, in get_connection
    klass = import_string(backend or settings.EMAIL_BACKEND)
  File "C:\Users\Doug\.virtualenvs\upgradetools-YX5Y8vBO\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "c:\users\doug\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    <source code not available>

Exception Type: ModuleNotFoundError at /accounts/signup/
Exception Value: No module named 'django.core.email'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct usage should be `mail` and not `email` as documented in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/email/#console-backend thus the error in your code when importing the non-existent `email` module.

Replace your setting of:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.email.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

To:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: Also I guess that some imports must be edited too: `from django.core.mail import send_mail` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/email/

Comment: Thank you Niel, that was killing me.  rzlvmp, I'll keep an eye on this but I think django-allauth takes care of this?